# How do I manipulate a string variable as it is passed to a command?

Tags: bash, gnome, linux-mint

I have a URI scheme handler which executes a command when called upon.  When I visit my-type//:example.com, Chrome and my desktop environment actually run this command: `some-command %u`

Where `some-command` is customizable by me, and `%u` is a variable containing the string `my-type//:example.com`.

So the command that actually gets executed is: `some-command my-type//:example.com`

What I would like to do is to alter `%u` such that it contains `example.com` instead of `my-type//:example.com`

How is this done?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more detail. What is this "URI scheme handler" and what language is it written in? How are these parameters getting passed?

Comment: The URI scheme handler is anything I want it to be.  It could be a script, or a browser, or any application.  What I'm asking about needs to happen before it reaches that program.  It's just whatever `some-command` is set to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow bash script as you command and pass it the real command name

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED_ARGS=2
E_BADARGS=65
# Check for proper number of command line args.
if [ $# -lt $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` commmand-for-pass-uri-without-scheme uri"
    echo "Example:  `basename $0` echo my-type://example.com"
    exit $E_BADARGS
fi

COMMAND=$1
URI=$2

# extract the protocol
proto="$(echo $URI | grep :// | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g')"
# remove the protocol -- updated
url=$(echo $URI | sed -e s,$proto,,g)
# extract the user (if any)
user="$(echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1)"
# extract the host -- updated
host=$(echo $url | sed -e s,$user@,,g | cut -d/ -f1)
# extract the path (if any)
path="$(echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-)"

$COMMAND $url
```

Name it as remove-scheme-and-call-command.sh for example and instead `some-command` set follow `remove-scheme-and-call-command some-command`

Don't forget to make your script executable with chmod +x and add script